# Как перемесить изображение?

Tags: java

Нужно,что бы при выборе изображения оно перемещалось в корневую папку программы, как это можно реализовать ? Пытался через Files.copy и Files.create(), но второму нужны какие-то странные аргументы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Если файл `target` уже существует, то `source` его затрет.

или

```
Files.move(source, target);
```

Если файл `target` уже существует, то `source` не будут перемещен.

Документация: [раз](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html), [два](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

Comment: А если мне нужно переместить не меняя файл ?

Comment: Что значит не меняя файл?

Comment: Что-бы не заменить уже существующий файл на новый, а просто переместить, не заменяя ничего

Comment: Я все равно не понял, но можно. Дайте файлу другое имя.

Comment: Ок, сейчас попробую !

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
    Files.copy(изначальныйПутьФайла, новыйПутьФайла, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```